# Triggering different functions on click event based on innherHTML

Tags: javascript, if-statement, events, dom

When I load page, change to green button displays.
When I click on that button, change to purple button displays.

But when I click on the button again (based on innherHTML), expected function(onePurple()) is not triggered, but twoGreen() is triggered.

I am trying to execute code based on innerHTML, but looks like it is not happening.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="existing-class">

        <li>This is li</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="MyElement">Change to two column - green</button>
    <p>red - default</p>
    <p>green - two columns</p>

</body>

</html>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is the js

```
const myButton = document.querySelector("#MyElement");
const oneColumnText = `Change to one column - purple`;
const twoColumnText = `Change to two column - green`;
var myClass = document.querySelector(".existing-class");

function twoGreen() {
    console.log("twoGreen function")
    myClass.classList.add("two");
    myButton.innerHTML = oneColumnText;
}

function onePurple() {
    console.log("onePurple function")
    myClass.classList.remove("two");
    myClass.classList.add("one");
    myButton.innerHTML = twoColumnText;
}

// window.onload = function() {
if (myButton.innerHTML === twoColumnText) {
    myButton.addEventListener('click', twoGreen, false);
}
if (myButton.innerHTML === oneColumnText) {
    myButton.addEventListener('click', onePurple, false);
}


// }
```

CSS:

```
.existing-class li {
    color: red;
}

.existing-class.two li {
    color: green;
}

.existing-class.one li {
    color: purple;
}
```

Here is the jsfillde:
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleuser2018/etkjv6x6/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, this way you will need to re-attach the `click` event whenever the `innerHTML` has changed, it will cause an infinite loop of attaching `click` event everytime the button was clicked.

The best approach here is to wrap the if blocks logic inside the event callback:

```
MyElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (MyElement.innerHTML === twoColumnText) {
    twoGreen();
  } else if (MyElement.innerHTML === oneColumnText) {
    onePurple();
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var MyElement = document.querySelector("#MyElement");
const oneColumnText = `Change to one column - purple`;
const twoColumnText = `Change to two column - green`;

function twoGreen() {
  console.log("twoGreen function")
  document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("two");
  document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.remove("one");
  MyElement.innerHTML = oneColumnText;
}

function onePurple() {
  console.log("onePurple function")
  document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.remove("two");
  document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("one");
  MyElement.innerHTML = twoColumnText;


}

MyElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (MyElement.innerHTML === twoColumnText) {
    twoGreen();
  } else if (MyElement.innerHTML === oneColumnText) {
    onePurple();
  }

});
```

```css
.existing-class li {
  color: red;
}

.existing-class.two li {
  color: green;
}

.existing-class.one li {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul class="existing-class">

  <li>This is li</li>
</ul>
<button id="MyElement">Change to two column - green</button>
<p>red - default</p>
<p>green - two columns</p>
```

Here's your [updated working **Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/etkjv6x6/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var MyElement = document.querySelector("#MyElement");
const oneColumnText = `Change to one column - purple`;
const twoColumnText = `Change to two column - green`;

function twoGreen() {
    console.log("twoGreen function")
    document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.remove("one");
    document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("two");
    MyElement.innerHTML = oneColumnText;
    MyElement.removeEventListener('click',twoGreen,false);
    MyElement.addEventListener('click', onePurple);
    
}

function onePurple() {
    console.log("onePurple function")
    document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.remove("two");
    document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("one");
    MyElement.innerHTML = twoColumnText;
    MyElement.removeEventListener('click',onePurple,false);
  MyElement.addEventListener('click', twoGreen);

}



// window.onload = function() {
if (MyElement.innerHTML === twoColumnText) {
    MyElement.addEventListener('click', twoGreen);
}
if (MyElement.innerHTML === oneColumnText) {
    MyElement.addEventListener('click', onePurple);
}
```

```css
.existing-class li {
    color: red;
}

.existing-class.two li {
    color: green;
}

.existing-class.one li {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="existing-class">

        <li>This is li</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="MyElement">Change to two column - green</button>
    <p>red - default</p>
    <p>green - two columns</p>

</body>

</html>
```

After functions are attached on window load you will need to update this on your clicks. Try the following:

```
function twoGreen() {
console.log("twoGreen function")
document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("two");
MyElement.innerHTML = oneColumnText;

MyElement.addEventListener('click', onePurple);
```

}

```
function onePurple() {
   console.log("onePurple function")
   document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.remove("two");
   document.querySelector(".existing-class").classList.add("one");
   MyElement.innerHTML = twoColumnText;
MyElement.addEventListener('click', twoGreen);

}
```

Comment: Really!! Reattaching the event handler in the event handler callback itself?! It will cause the infine loop of attaching the events. Have you read my answer?